# Declaring an if statement in jquery to show date or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I have three input fields on a page that render dynamically and use the class `.datepicker`.

I am using this jquery to show the kendoDatePicker on each of the inputs based on the class.

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $(".datepicker").kendoDatePicker({
        value:new Date()
    });
    $(".datetimepicker").kendoDateTimePicker({
        value:new Date()
    });
});
```

What I need to achieve is something like this:

if the input has a default value do not use `value:new Date()` if the input does not have a default value use `value:new Date()`.

Basically I need the three inputs to render with the datetimepicker but only include a default value date if they don't have a value on render.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could loop over the elements, and for each one:

1. Grab the current value
2. Assign a date picker
3. Use the current value or a `new Date()` if empty as a default

Here's what that might look like:

```
$(function() {
    $(".datepicker").each(function() {
        var currentValue = $(this).val();
        $(this).kendoDatePicker({
            value: currentValue == '' ? new Date() : currentValue
        });
    });
    $(".datetimepicker").each(function() { 
        var currentValue = $(this).val();
        $(this).kendoDateTimePicker({
            value: currentValue == '' ? new Date() : currentValue
        });
    });
});
```